# Distinguish instance and static inner classes declared in the initializer

Tags: java, reflection

While trying to answer a question here on SO, I came across an theoretic problem where I'm not sure whether a better solution exists:

Suppose we have the following setup:

```
class A {
  public A(Outer o) {
  }
}

class Outer {
  static A staticA = new A( new Outer() ) {
    ...
  };

  A innerA = new A( new Outer() ) {
    ...
  };
}
```

How would I distinguish between the inner class and the static inner class using reflection?

From my tests I could only tell which is the static inner class by checking the parameter types of the constructors, i.e. the class of `innerA` only provides a constructor taking two `Outer` instances.  (I tested every flag or data on the enclosing classes/methods I could think of, and everything was equal - but I might have missed something.)

When comparing those two classes I could determine which one is the static inner class by checking whose constructors have less parameters of the outer type (in this case the static inner class' constructors would have one less).

However, suppose I don't know much about the class and I especially don't know whether the constructor has any explicit parameter of the outer type, i.e. whether `A` had a no argument constructor or a constructor taking an `Outer` argument (like in the case above). In that situation I couldn't safely tell whether the class is an inner or static inner class.

Is there another, i.e. safe, way?

Just for the record: this is a theoretical problem, I'm currently not trying to achieve anything.

*Edit*:

Here's my SSCCE:

```
package sscce;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ReflectionTest {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    Outer o = new Outer();

    o.innerA.reflect();
    o.staticA.reflect();
  }
}

class A {

  public A( Outer o ) {

  }

  public void reflect() {
    Class<?> c = getClass();
    Class<?> e = c.getEnclosingClass();
    Class<?> d = c.getDeclaringClass();
    Constructor<?> enc = c.getEnclosingConstructor();
    Method m = c.getEnclosingMethod();

    System.out.println("class: " + c.getName());
    System.out.println("-------------------");
    System.out.println("enclosing class: " + e);
    System.out.println("enclosing ctor: " + enc);
    System.out.println("enclosing method: " + m);
    System.out.println("declaring class: " + d);

    System.out.println("anonymous: " + c.isAnonymousClass());
    System.out.println("local: " + c.isLocalClass());
    System.out.println("synth: " + c.isSynthetic());
    System.out.println("member: " + c.isMemberClass());
    System.out.println("modifiers: " + c.getModifiers());

    for( Constructor<?> ctr : c.getDeclaredConstructors() ) {
      System.out.println("constructor params:"  + Arrays.toString( ctr.getParameterTypes()) );
    }

    System.out.println();
  }
}

class Outer {
  public static A staticA = new A(new Outer()) {};
  public A innerA = new A(this) {};
}
```

And the output:

```
class: sscce.Outer$2 //this is innerA
-------------------
enclosing class: class sscce.Outer
enclosing ctor: null
enclosing method: null
declaring class: null
anonymous: true
local: false
synth: false
member: false
modifiers: 0
constructor params:[class sscce.Outer, class sscce.Outer]

class: sscce.Outer$1  //this is staticA 
-------------------
enclosing class: class sscce.Outer
enclosing ctor: null
enclosing method: null
declaring class: null
anonymous: true
local: false
synth: false
member: false
modifiers: 0
constructor params:[class sscce.Outer]
```

*Edit 2*:

For completeness I added some other cases and those are all distinguishable (except the current which is last in the list):

- "Normal" inner classes (`class Outer { class Inner {}}`) have a declaring class and are flagged being member classes
- "Normal" static inner classes (`class Outer { static class Inner {}}`) have a declaring class, are member classes *and* have the static class modifier
- Inner classes created in an instance method have an enclosing method
- Inner classes created in a static method have an eclosing method which has the static modifier
- Inner classes created in an initializer (static or instance) are the case described here and don't differ except in the constructor parameters

Comment: I don't see any inner classes, just one static variable and one instance variable.

Comment: @GriffeyDog: Look more carefully - note the braces at the end of `new A(...) {}`.

Comment: @Jon Right you are, I missed those.

Comment: @GriffeyDog I'll try to make the formatting clearer :)

Comment: Could you post some code of how you are reflecting on the class? I don't quite understand exactly what you are trying to determine, however for sure you can check the modifiers of the staticA and see that it is a static field. But again, I don't really understand what you are trying to determine.

Comment: @Sam, sure I'll add my checking code and the results.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring two anonymous inner classes inside `Outer`.

Theoretically (i.e. I didn't test it), I suppose you can call:

```
Class<?>[] classes = Outer.class.getDeclaredClasses();
for(Class<?> c : classes) {
  if ((c.getModifiers() & Modifier.STATIC) != 0) {
    // its a static inner class (or interface)
  }
  else {
    // its a non static inner class or interface
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the modifiers are equal. That was one of the first things I tested. :)

Comment: Besides that, `Outer.class.getDeclaredClasses()` returns an empty array.